# Convert static object to Observable and forkjoin

Tags: angular, typescript, object, rxjs, observable

I have an object and need to combine it with an observable.

The object looks like this:

**obj1**

```
let org1Obj = {"category": "1", "testkey": "testvalue"}
```

The results with JSON.stringify of the observable looks like this:

**obj2**

```
[{"id":"51XXgI1w77VerovThbUV","question":"Sdad"},
 {"id":"FxjDsyLBGqtrBx1EHFyM","question":"exanoke"}]
```

I then have an observable that fetches data and I'm thinking of using forkJoin to combine the two so I end up with the following result:

```
{"category": "1", 
 "testkey": "testvalue", 
 "questions": [
   {"name": "test1"},
   {"name": "test"}
 ]
}
```

How do I make org1Obj into an observable so I can use forkJoin on it and how can I add the second observable to "questions": [**result from observable**]?

Comment: Converting a value to an observable that emits a single value? It looks like a misuse of observables. This could be done with simple `map`. The way how exactly they should be combined remains unclear since the values of the result differ from original objects.

Comment: The reason I need to convert it is so that I can use forkJoin and the reason for forkJoin is because I need to wait until all the data is available from the second observable. If I try to just combine them the data won't be available from the second observable before the function is run.

Comment: Since static object is already available, resulting data will be available in observable `map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible with:

```
const observable1 = Observable.of(obj1);
return Observable.forkJoin(observable1, observable2).map(([obj1, obj2]) => {
  return Object.assign({}, obj1, { questions: obj2 }); // or so
});
```

And less complicated and more performant way to do this is to skip `forkJoin` and map an observable to resulting object:

```
return observable2.map(obj2 => {
  return Object.assign({}, obj1, { questions: obj2 }); // or so
});
```

Comment: Probably `return Object.assign({}, obj1, { questions: obj2 });`?

Comment: Probably, but it isn't clear what are data input and output from the question. I guess this is out of scope of the subject.

Comment: I was thinking it is clear what the final shape will be.

Comment: I see what you mean, yes, I guess it's closer this way, thanks (though obj2 still doesn't look like expected questions, probably the array is supposed to be mapped or something)

Comment: Ah, yes indeed!

Comment: I'm marking it as the accepted answer, I chose the second method with a slight variation of using subscribe directly instead of map.